# How to create local post on google using PHP MyBusiness API?

Tags: php, google-api, google-my-business-api

I want to create local post on google using google's PHP My Business API V4.

Sample code is below

```
$mybusinessService = new \Google_Service_MyBusiness($client);
$local = new \Google_Service_MyBusiness_LocalPost();

$path = $locname.'/localPosts';
$response = $mybusinessService->accounts_locations_localPosts->create($path,$local);
```

where $locname is string of accounts/locations id.

above code throws exception 'Request contains an invalid argument.'

I want to know that how to create post or post data using PHP api.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For brands that have more than ten locations are not allowed to post on GMB through the API. Pull the location and check this flag `$location->getLocationState()->getIsLocalPostApiDisabled()`.

> Posting on GMB Ex.

```
        $posts = $mybusinessService->accounts_locations_localPosts;

        $newPost = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_LocalPost();

        $newPost->setSummary("Order your Thanksgiving turkeys now!!");          
        $newPost->setLanguageCode("en-US");
        $calltoaction = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_CallToAction();

        $calltoaction->setActionType("ORDER");

        $calltoaction->setUrl("http://google.com/order_turkeys_here");

        $newPost->setCallToAction($calltoaction);

        $media = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_MediaItem();

        $media->setMediaFormat("PHOTO");
        $media->setSourceUrl("https://www.google.com/real-turkey-photo.jpg");

        $newPost->setMedia($media); 

        $listPostsResponse = $posts->create($location_name, $newPost);
```

Comment: Something to note is that sourceUrl needs to be a valid URL or google will send back an "INVALID_ARGUMENT" error

Comment: Can we include a video in uploading Posts via Google My Business API

Comment: I am also having INVALID_ARGUMENT error