# Create Local post on Google My Business Issue

Tags: php, google-api

Attempting to create Google My Business Local Post using My Business API and PHP.
A Local Post is created just fine EXCEPT when adding the mediaItem object to the post body.
Getting the error :
     {
        "error": {
            "code": 400,
            "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
            "errors": [{
                "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "badRequest"
            }],
            "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
        }
     }

```
    Below is the post object with mediaItem that is being sent to localPosts->create

    $new_post = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_LocalPost();
    $new_post->setSummary('Hello World');
    $new_post->setLanguageCode('en-US');    
    $media = new Google_Service_MyBusiness_MediaItem();
    $media->setMediaFormat("PHOTO");
    $media->setSourceUrl("https://www.webyhub.com/img/logo.png");
    $new_post->setMedia($media);
```

Comment: this is not codeigniter issue you should ask for google business issue refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766904/how-to-create-local-post-on-google-using-php-mybusiness-api

Comment: what I am doing wrong here. Image is not posting in the above code.Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this on Postman to get the detail validation message as to why the image you used is invalid.

Try Advanced Rest Client (or Postman), make a POST request to [https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{uuid}/locations/{uuid}/localPosts](https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/%7Buuid%7D/locations/%7Buuid%7D/localPosts) with 
Header: **Authorization: Bearer {access_token}.**
Body Content Type: **application/json**

Body:

```
{
  "summary":"test",
  "topicType":"STANDARD",
  "media":[{"mediaFormat": "PHOTO","sourceUrl": "https://example.com/files/test.jpg"}]
}
```

Also, Creating Post with video uploading is not currently available. I dont know why but I am also stuck on this matter.